# if form in exceptions: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in Python nltk

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, lemmatization

I got following error.

```
 if form in exceptions: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Following is my code.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

sentence = 'missed you'
w_tokenize = (word_tokenize(sentence))

for word in w_tokenize:
  print WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w_tokenize,'v')
```

Can anyone tell me how can I fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have the variables mixed up, it should be

```
for word in w_tokenize:
  print WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word,'v')
```

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake. Anyway, Can I get the output to a list like ['miss','you']

Comment: Like this: `print [WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word,'v') for word in w_tokenize]` ?

Comment: No. It seems like ['miss']
['you']. But it is not I expected.

Comment: I want to get them into one list.

Comment: Thank you. Here what is mean by u in [u'miss]?

Comment: @ChathurikaJayawardana [Unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type)